# Find the value of $\frac{9}{5}(a+b)$ given that $a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}=183$ and $a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}=182$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

> Suppose $a,b$ are positive real numbers such that $a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}=183$, $a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}=182$. Find $\frac{9}{5}(a+b)$.

It is my equation. I subtracted the second equation from the first one and found $(a-b)(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=1$.or, $(a-b)^2=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$.

Am I going to the right path? How to escape from this. Please give me hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  let $\,u=\sqrt{a}\,$ and $\,v=\sqrt{b}\,$, then it's given that $\,u^3+v^3=183\,$ and $\,u^2v+uv^2=182\,$, and the problem asks for $\frac{9}{5}(u^2+v^2)$.

- $\;(u+v)^3=u^3 + v^3 + 3(u^2v+ uv^2) = 183 + 3 \cdot 182 = 729 \implies u+v = 9\,$
- $\;uv= (u^2v+uv^2)/(u+v) = 182 / 9  \,$
- $\;u^2+v^2 = (u+v)^2 - 2 uv = \cdots \,$

Comment: Nice! +1 ... Maybe it is easier to follow the solution with replacing square roots with something like $x=\sqrt{a}$ and $y=\sqrt{b}$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Maybe, indeed. Edited the answer to make it more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^2=a$ and $B^2=b$ then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^3+B^3 = 183 \\
A^2B+B^2 A =182
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the second equation by $3$ and add the first
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^3+B^3+ 3(A^2B+B^2 A)  =(A+B)^3= 729 \\
A+B =9 \\
AB = \frac{182}{9} \\
(A-B)^2=(A+B)^2-4AB= \frac{1}{9} \\
A= \frac{14}{3} \\
B= \frac{13}{3} 
\end{eqnarray*}
So $ \frac{9}{5} (a+b) = \color{red}{73}$.